# Is there any way to hide Vaadin Notifications?

Tags: java, notifications, vaadin

Requirement: hide active Vaadin [Notifications](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Notification.html) when the user navigates to a different page.

How can this be achieved? The only suitable method that seems elligible for hiding would seem to be `notification.setDelayMsec(0);`, since there is no hide method provided.

Is there some kind of page change event that can be used?

Comment: With a "page change" you mean the use of Navigator/View?

Comment: @cfrick I think that would be the use of View, yes.

Comment: The same link you shared describes multiple notification types that behave differently depending on the type, some disappearing as soon as the user moves the mouse or uses the keyboard. So, what kind of messages are you using?

Comment: @Morfic that would be a regular Vaadin Notification with delay (`setDelayMsec(3000);`). It has a title, message and is of type `Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do that, but there is a [enhancement request](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/2114) in Vaadin issue tracker to add that functionality. Please vote for the issue if you would like this to be added.